# Turtles not finding (0,0)

Tags: netlogo

I've got 6 turtles that are supposed to run a search of the world. They start at the origin (0,0) and head in a straight line until the hit the edge of the world, then they face back towards the origin and work their way back. They are supposed to stop once they reach the origin, the problem is that they aren't stopping at the origin. They continue to the opposite wall and bounce off of that.

Here's the code:

```
to searching
  if not can-move? 1 [
    set return-to-base true
    set label "RTB"
    go-home]
  forward 1
end

to go-home
  ifelse pxcor = 0 and pycor = 0 [
    set return-to-base false
    set label ""
    stop]
  [ facexy 0 0 ]
  forward 1
end
```

The "RTB" label never gets reset, which tells me that even though the turtles are crossing the origin, they aren't actually seeing (0,0)?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) What is your exact error? How do we reproduce it? Do you have enough info in your code for someone else here to reproduce your error?

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, the issue is that the turtles are supposed to stop when they get back to the origin (0,0). They don't stop at the origin, they continue straight through it and bounce off the far edge, rinse and repeat. So for whatever reason, the turtles are not seeing the location (0,0) even though they are passing right through it. That's what I need help with.

Comment: That is not what I asked. You are explaining the goal you are trying to achieve, but there is no mentioning of the coding error you are trying to solve. There is no mentioning of how you approached your problem, or what did you try. So you expect just a ready solution here?

Comment: The error is that the the turtles don't stop when they get to (0,0). Not sure I can make it any more plain. As I said above, since the "RTB" label isn't being reset, so I think the turtles aren't seeing (0,0). If I knew what I was doing wrong, I could fix it, but I don't. I don't expect someone to write the program for me, but a pointer in the right direction would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The below code does what I want it to do.

```
to searching
  if not can-move? 1 [
    set return-to-base true
    set label "RTB"]
  if return-to-base [go-home]
  forward 1
end

to go-home
  ifelse pxcor <= 1 and pxcor >= -1 and pycor <= 1 and pycor >= -1 [
    set label ""
    set return-to-base false
    stop]
  [facexy 0 0]
  forward 1
end
```